# Install make 4.2 on "Amazon Linux AMI"

Tags: amazon-web-services

How I can install make 4.2 on "Amazon Linux AMI" ?

I try

```
sudo yum install devtoolset-7-make
```

but I receive a package not found

Answer (score 0):

You should install the tools as specified here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/compile-software.html

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```